# Map attribute routes of a dynamically loaded Web API 2 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 project with some predefined Controllers and I'm creating the routes using attribute routing.

I have another class library with a web API 2 custom controller and loaded dynamically once its requested;

But the problem is the attribute routing on the above custom controller is not considered at all. Is there any way to inject the custom controller routes to the main Web API project?

Following is the way I'm loading the custom controller to web API project;

Using a custom http controller selector if a requested controller is not found on the Web API project I load the class library and try to load the requested controller from it.

**CustomHttpControllerSelector.cs**

```
public class CustomHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
    {
        private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

    public CustomHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpControllerDescriptor controller;
        try
        {
            //Select the requested controller
            controller = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Try to load the requested controller from the custom dll
            controller = GetCustomContoller(request);
        }
        return controller;
    }

    private HttpControllerDescriptor GetCustomContoller(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpControllerDescriptor controller;

        try
        {
            string controllerName = base.GetControllerName(request);
            string controllerFormatName = string.Format("{0}Controller", controllerName);
            string applicationPath = string.Format(@"{0}\PlugIns\CustomModules.dll", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath);

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(applicationPath);
            if (assembly == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "CustomModules.dll not found."));

            Type controllerType = assembly.GetTypes()
              .Where(i => typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(i))
              .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.Equals(controllerFormatName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (controllerType == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, string.Format("{0} not found.", controllerFormatName)));

            controller = new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, controllerType);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return controller;
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   // Web API configuration and services
    config
       .Services
       .Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomHttpControllerSelector(config));

   // Web API routes
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );            
}
```

**Custom Controller - AdministrationController.cs**

```
    [RoutePrefix("Administration")]
    public class AdministrationController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new List<string>() { "Item 01", "Item 02", "Item 03" };
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Access")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAccess()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Access Granted.");
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Info")]
        public DataTable GetInfo()
        {
            return new DataTable();
        }
    }
```

The `AdministrationController` is not available in the original web API project so when I issue a `GET` request like `http://localhost:53076/Administration` the `AdministrationController` should be loaded from CustomModules.all and the method `Get` should be executed. But instead of the list expected, I'm getting a message as follows;

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   Get on type CustomModules.AdministrationController
>   GetAccess on type CustomModules.AdministrationController
>   GetInfo on type CustomModules.AdministrationController"

This clearly indicates that the attribute routing I provided is not considered. Any fix for this?

Comment: Try implementing custom `IAssembliesResolver` for resolving the required assemblies instead of _dynamically_ loading it in `HttpControllerSelector`. For references: https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @IronGeek Thanks. I tried it. The requirement is not all the controllers in the custom library should be loaded. Only the requested module needs to be loaded. I can achieve this by simply referencing the custom dll and calling a `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` from custom dll.